# '>=' not supported between instances of 'method' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods, compiler-errors, typeerror

Here is the method causing the error:

```
class Kilpailu():
    def __init__(self, nimi, pituuskm, osallistujat):
        self.nimi = nimi
        self.pituuskm = pituuskm
        self.osallistujat = osallistujat

    def kilpailu_ohi(self):
        for i in self.osallistujat:
            if (i.getKuljettuMatka>=self.pituuskm):
                return True
            else:
                return False
```

edit: here is also where getKuljettuMatka is defined

```
class Auto:
    def __init__(self, rekisteritunnus, huippunopeus):
        self.rekisteritunnus = rekisteritunnus
        self.huippunopeus=huippunopeus
        self.nopeus=0
        self.KuljettuMatka=0
    def getKuljettuMatka(self):
        return int(self.KuljettuMatka)
```

I am trying to call the method that just returns a boolean value and print whether the value is true or false.

```
class main():
    autot = []
    for i in range(10):
        auto = Auto("ABC-" + str(i + 1), random.randint(100, 200))
        autot.append(auto)

    k = Kilpailu("Suuri romuralli", 8000, autot)
    tunnit = 0
    print(k.kilpailu_ohi()) #Should return true/false, instead throws an error
```

and here is the actual console output for the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/ohjelmisto1/Harjoitustehtävät/Assosisaatio/autoKilpailu.py", line 51, in <module>
    class main():
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/ohjelmisto1/Harjoitustehtävät/Assosisaatio/autoKilpailu.py", line 59, in main
    print(k.kilpailu_ohi())
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/ohjelmisto1/Harjoitustehtävät/Assosisaatio/autoKilpailu.py", line 45, in kilpailu_ohi
    if (i.getKuljettuMatka>=self.pituuskm):
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'method' and 'int'
```

I have tried changing stuff in the method like variable names in case i was accidentally overwriting something but it didnt work either

Comment: Where is `getKuljettuMatka` defined? The error says that its a method of the class.

Comment: @tdelaney
I just edited the post to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`def getKuljettuMatka(self):` defines `.getKuljettuMatka` on instances of `Auto` as a method (that happens to return an integer). You can *call* the method with `i.getKuljettuMatka()` (note the parentheses), but what you're doing is comparing the method itself to `self.pituuskm`, which is an integer, and that doesn't work.

Instead:

```
    def kilpailu_ohi(self):
        for i in self.osallistujat:
            if (i.getKuljettuMatka() >= self.pituuskm):
                return True
            else:
                return False
```

By the way, I think the code is a bit roundabout in other ways, but this is you main issue right now.